# how to evaluate indirect references in Makefile

Tags: shell, makefile

I have got stuck at a step while writing a Makefile.
I have following code :

```
set_var:
  @ NUM=0 ; while [[ $$NUM < 1 ]]; do \
        echo "I am here"; \
         echo $$NUM  dump$${NUM}.txt; \
         var="SSA_CORE$${NUM}_MAINEXEC" ; \
         echo $$var ; \
                 var1=$${!var}; \ 
                 echo $$var1; \
         (( NUM = NUM + 1)); \
                  done
all:set_var
```

here SSA_CORE0_MAINEXEC is an environment variable whose value is already set using setenv .So I want that value to get evaluated or printed using variable var1. I tried it as shown above but not working. pLease help.

Comment: Could you elaborate not working?  What does it say?  Aren't you using `csh` syntax here?

Comment: Not working means I am not getting expected output.What syntax or code I shd use to get the value of env variable ssa_core0_mainexec using the concatenation of strings and variables.

Comment: So ... What do you expect as output? What do you actually get as output?

Comment: setenv SSA_CORE0_MAINEXEC abc , so when I do echo $$var1 it shd give abc as output.

Comment: I have got the correct syntax for this ,                                     var1=$${!var}; \
echo $$var1; \ , its giving me desired o/p , thanks !!